# How to know where a file was before it was moved

Tags: mv, restore

Why does find match all the files when using it like this?

```
    find ~/ "*.pdf"
```

So, I accidentally messed up with my home directory and moved all the files into ~/Documents. Is there a way to undo that mv and bring back all the files as they were before.

If I can't do it, I would like to know to know how to restore my ~ directory with all the config files in place.

Comment: If it shows all the pdf files then its expected.

Comment: It shows every single file with whatever extension.

Comment: I think you need a space between '~/' and "*.pdf".

Comment: What do you expect from the first command? Maybe you mean `find ~/ -name "*.pdf"` or maybe you mean `echo ~/"*.pdf"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question contains two completely unrelated questions. Please keep it to one question per question.

> Why does find match all the files when using it like this?

You have asked `find` to search in your home directory (`~/`) plus in a file called `*.pdf` (which probably does not exist) for... everything, since you didn't specify any search criteria.

Did you actually mean this?

```
find ~/ -name "*.pdf"
```

> Is there a way to undo that mv and bring back all the files as they were before.

Check where the files can be found on your backups. Otherwise, no, there is no way.

Comment: Actually I added a -exec which would move all the stuff to my ~/Documents. But I forgot to add -name and ended up with moving everything in ~/ to ~/Documents. Thanks for the help.